# Change Azure VM size once deployed too production?

Tags: azure

I have 2 small vm machines deployed for a web role. I cant find anywhere where I can change the size of the VM once its deployed, for example to a medium machine.

The only way is to do a redeployment.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible, you need to redeploy package with new size, but you can change the number of instances.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/0652d2e7-4469-4b30-b100-dd82485ceffd